# How to transform bmp into table (formatted txt, xls) with rgb values?

Tags: c#, bmp

I am analyzing an image, with main problem being determining the brightness of an object and contrast between it and background. However, due to object having cell-like structure, with lots of internal spaces with background in it, pixels with background color make too much of a way into selection I use to determine brightness, spoiling the result.
I want to filter all pixels with backfround color out of selection altogether and, since picture-analyzing tool I am using (imageJ) does not allow it, filtering coresponding pixels in table seems to be a rational course.

Using c#, how can I accomplish this task?
Alternatively, any existent solutions would be welcome

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it done with System.Drawing.Bitmap.